# Boostrap 5 carousel with multi item and infinite and not jQuery

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5, infinity

I'm looking for but can't find a convincing resource on a carousel with several items displayed at the same time using boostrap 5 without jQuery.

Do you have an idea to make this element witch boostrap 5 with an infinite defiments (that is to say that we never arrive at the end, once all the items pass, it refreshes the first) ?